# VueJS - pass data to component with existing row

Tags: vue.js, components

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baibai/yrL730x8/1/)

```
data: {
address_components: [
    { id:1, city_id:1, area_id: 100}
],
city_id:0,
area_id:0,
sort:1
```

},

I need to pass data to existing row, is that incorrect?

And if I add a new row, the id should be '2'

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlziK.jpg)

what is the good way to do this? :'-(

Answer (score 0):

modify your code like this:

```
addComponent() {
  this.address_components.push({id:++this.sort})
},
```

Comment: but if there is not an existing row, the id will be start with 2...?

Comment: the init value of sort is 0

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a list in your data() and just push a object there.

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>

var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods:
  {
  Add:function()
  {
     //process the inputs and push it to items list
     this.items.push({ message: "Hi"})

  }
  }
})
```

Did not tested this and just created from example from Vue Documentation but you got the idea. Pushing a new item in list will automatically updates the component or the element